# Screen contents look so big in 1280 × 720 resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I am new to Ubuntu 20.04 and don't know much about it.

I have my current screen resolution set as 1920 × 1080 (16:9). I want to change it to 1280 × 720 (16:9); but as soon as I apply settings, everything becomes bigger. I have tried a lot of things, but still can't fix it.

Screenshot of 1920 × 1080 resolution:

[image: Screenshot of 1920 × 1080 resolution]

Screenshot of 1280 × 720 resolution:

[image: Screenshot of 1280 × 720 resolution]

Output of `xrandr`:

[image: Screenshot of output of xrandr]

I do not want the screen contents to increase in size after changing resolution to 1280 × 720. Please help me out.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the screen resolution?  What is the actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @Nmath Basically I  want to record my school online classes , resolution of 1920 × 1080 result in a bigger file size on the other hand my friend records in a resolution 1280 × 720 which result in smaller file size,

Comment: How are you recording?  This is something you generally adjust in whatever software you use to record.  You wouldn't change your screen resolution for that. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @Nmath I use simple screen recorder

Comment: I have never used the software but if it's [this software](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/), a screenshot of the application shows the option to "scale video" and also allows you to reduce the frame rate.  Why don't you use these options in the screen recording software to reduce file size?

Answer (score 3):

This is a normal behavior. Smaller resolutions will result in bigger things all over you desktop, games, apps...

Comment: hi But i have maintained the aspect ratio

Comment: Correct, so nothing it distorted. A lower resolution means, everything has less pixels to show, but you monitor does not shrink by changing the resolution, so it has to scale it and everything appears bigger.

Comment: A square 10cm x 10cm has a 1:1 aspect ratio.  So does a square 100cm x 100cm.  Unless your display is a CRT (unlikely with 16:9) you really should only ever use the native screen resolution. Anything else is going to look bad.